# Update particular record on click of specific submit button

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a Jsp page which displays several records from database and with each data row there is a submit button on its click servlet updates the database.

For example my JSP displays:-
CustomerName  Customer City   SubmitButton.

So I want that submit button next to whichever customer is pressed the data for that customer should be updated.

I m able to display the data in jsp with submit buttons but not able to update the records from servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put each submit button in its own form with a hidden field wherein you pass the row ID.

```
<td>
    <form action="servleturl" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${customer.id}" />
    </form>
</td>
```

Then you can just grab it by

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
Customer customer = customerDAO.find(Long.valueOf(id));
// ...
```